# Trilateration and locating the point (x,y,z)

Tags: algorithm, localization, geometry, triangulation, trilateration

I want to find the coordinate of an unknown node which lie somewhere in the space which has its reference distance away from 3 or more nodes which all of them have known coordinate.

This problem is exactly like Trilateration as described here [Trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration).

However, I don't understand the part about "Preliminary and final computations" (refer to the wikipedia site). I don't get where I could find P1, P2 and P3 just so I can put to those equation?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Trilateration is the process of finding the center of the area of intersection of three spheres. The center point and radius of each of the three spheres must be known.

Let's consider your three example centerpoints P1 [-1,1], P2 [1,1], and P3 [-1,-1]. The first requirement is that P1' be at the origin, so let us adjust the points accordingly by adding an offset vector V [1,-1] to all three:

```
P1' = P1 + V = [0, 0]
P2' = P2 + V = [2, 0]
P3' = P3 + V = [0,-2]
```

Note: Adjusted points are denoted by the ' (prime) annotation.

P2' must also lie on the x-axis. In this case it already does, so no adjustment is necessary.

We will assume the radius of each sphere to be 2.

Now we have 3 equations (given) and 3 unknowns (X, Y, Z of center-of-intersection point).

Solve for P4'x:

```
x = (r1^2 - r2^2 + d^2) / 2d  //(d,0) are coords of P2'
x = (2^2 - 2^2 + 2^2) / 2*2
x = 1
```

Solve for P4'y:

```
y = (r1^2 - r3^2 + i^2 + j^2) / 2j - (i/j)x //(i,j) are coords of P3'
y = (2^2 - 2^2 + 0 + -2^2) / 2*-2 - 0
y = -1
```

Ignore z for 2D problems.

P4' = [1,-1]

Now we translate back to original coordinate space by subtracting the offset vector V:

P4 = P4' - V = [0,0]

The solution point, P4, lies at the origin as expected.

The second half of the article is describing a method of representing a set of points where P1 is not at the origin or P2 is not on the x-axis such that they fit those constraints. I prefer to think of it instead as a translation, but both methods will result in the same solution.

**Edit: Rotating P2' to the x-axis**

If P2' does not lie on the x-axis after translating P1 to the origin, we must perform a rotation on the view.

First, let's create some new vectors to use as an example:
P1 = [2,3]
P2 = [3,4]
P3 = [5,2]

Remember, we must first translate P1 to the origin. As always, the offset vector, V, is -P1. In this case, V = [-2,-3]

```
P1' = P1 + V = [2,3] + [-2,-3] = [0, 0]
P2' = P2 + V = [3,4] + [-2,-3] = [1, 1]
P3' = P3 + V = [5,2] + [-2,-3] = [3,-1]
```

To determine the angle of rotation, we must find the angle between P2' and [1,0] (the x-axis).

We can use the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) equality:

```
A dot B = ||A|| ||B|| cos(theta)
```

When B is [1,0], this can be simplified: A dot B is always just the X component of A, and ||B|| (the magnitude of B) is always a multiplication by 1, and can therefore be ignored.

We now have Ax = ||A|| cos(theta), which we can rearrange to our final equation:

```
theta = acos(Ax / ||A||)
```

or in our case:

```
theta = acos(P2'x / ||P2'||)
```

We calculate the magnitude of P2' using ||A|| = sqrt(Ax + Ay + Az)

```
||P2'|| = sqrt(1 + 1 + 0) = sqrt(2)
```

Plugging that in we can solve for theta

```
theta = acos(1 / sqrt(2)) = 45 degrees
```

Now let's use the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to rotate the scene by -45 degrees.
Since P2'y is positive, and the rotation matrix rotates counter-clockwise, we'll use a negative rotation to align P2 to the x-axis (if P2'y is negative, don't negate theta).

```
R(theta) = [cos(theta) -sin(theta)]
           [sin(theta)  cos(theta)]

  R(-45) = [cos(-45) -sin(-45)]
           [sin(-45)  cos(-45)]
```

We'll use double prime notation, '', to denote vectors which have been both translated and rotated.

```
P1'' = [0,0] (no need to calculate this one)

P2'' = [1 cos(-45) - 1 sin(-45)] = [sqrt(2)] = [1.414]
       [1 sin(-45) + 1 cos(-45)] = [0]       = [0]

P3'' = [3 cos(-45) - (-1) sin(-45)] = [sqrt(2)]    = [ 1.414]
       [3 sin(-45) + (-1) cos(-45)] = [-2*sqrt(2)] = [-2.828]
```

Now you can use P1'', P2'', and P3'' to solve for P4''. Apply the reverse rotation to P4'' to get P4', then the reverse translation to get P4, your center point.

To undo the rotation, multiply P4'' by R(-theta), in this case R(45). To undo the translation, subtract the offset vector V, which is the same as adding P1 (assuming you used -P1 as your V originally).

Comment: I don't know how I get those Point P1, P2 and P3. I mean for each of the reference known node, I have its x,y,z coordinate.

Comment: P1 is the point (which consists of a pair of X,Y coords) at the center of the first reference node. Likewise for P2 and P3. If you have the reference coordinates, you have P1, P2, and P3. They are one and the same.

Comment: I set up a test coordinates just to verify the math and it did not give me the correct result that is why i am confuse.

This is my set up:

p1 = (-1,1)
p2 = (1,1)
p3 = (-1,-1)

From the equation I found:
ex = (1,0)
i = 0
ey = (0,-1)
d = 2

and so to find x and y i use the other equations and i get

x = 1
y = 1

Which is wrong. I expect to see x = 0 and y = 0.
Note: In this case, I use r1 = sqrt(2) = r2 = r3

Can you spot the problem in the calculation?

Comment: I rewrote my answer to hopefully be much more helpful. Let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dan: I've been studying the same wikipedia page and came across your answer, it's been quite helpful in getting me to wrap my mind around the concept. I've implemented the first part of the article into an algorithm, however I'm having trouble doing the 2nd part (i.e translations). Could you perhaps give an example of a scenario with coordinates where the 2nd requirement (i.e. moving P2' to the x-axis) is also necessary?

Comment: @Yazid: I've edited my answer to include the step for rotating the scene in order to align P2' with the x-axis. Please feel free to ask for clarification or suggest corrections to any mistakes you may find. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dan: Gave it a try, not 100% sure of my translation of the math into my algorithm but I got P4=[4.5,5.5]. Is this right?

Comment: @Yazid: It depends what you assumed to be the radius of the 3 circles. I only provided center points for the translate/rotate example. To triangulate P4, the center point of the intersection of the circles, you need to "use P1'', P2'', and P3'' to solve for P4''", which means plugging the adjusted center points and their respective radii into the equations in the first half (where I assumed radius = 2 for all three circles).

Comment: @Dan: Yup I tested against your latest P1 P2 P3 coordinates above and assumed a radius of 2 for all three. Just wanted to verify my algorithm to see if the math works out with yours. If you also got [4.5, 5.5], I'll probably consider it as correct.

Comment: @Yazid: If you graph the circles, you should see that the center of their intersection is roughly [3.5, 2.5]. Did you forget to apply the translation at the end to get back to the original coordinate system?

Comment: @Dan: Sorry, had some bracketing mistakes in my P4''x formula which made the calculations wrong. Now it returns [3.5, 2.5] so it seems to work for the above set of coordinates. However, when I change the scenario slightly, i.e. P3 = [5,1], I get P4 = [4.5, 3.5]. When the circles are graphed, visually I would've assumed the result to be roughly [3.6, 2.3]. I don't think it's my original translations as I get [0,0], [0, 1.414], and [2.828, 0.1414] for P1'' P2'' and P3'' respectively, same as yours. Perhaps it's my P4'' formulas. My end translations are already applied and working correctly.

Comment: @Yazid: It may be a mistake in the rotation. Since it rotates counter-clockwise you may need to use -45 instead of 45 (assuming the angle is 45 as it is in the example above). This depends on which way the vector needs to be rotated to be aligned with the x-axis. The goal is to get P1 to the origin and P2 on the x-axis. How exactly you get there isn't important, so long as you remember to reverse the steps you used after triangulating in the new coord system to get back to the original coord system.

Comment: @Yazid: I fixed the sign error in the post with regard to R(-45). Perhaps that will help you.

Comment: @Dan: That did the trick! Thanks a lot, you've been very helpful. The math is pretty sound now. FYI, I managed to achieve the same result in determining the angle of rotation by doing `ATAN2(P2'x-P1'x, P2'y-P1'y)`. Also, I found out that the formula I have breaks (with a zero division error) if all circles share the same Y value. It's the P4''y formula that produces it, specifically the `(i/j)` part (when all Ys are equal, j = 0). In my application this will be a rare scenario so personally I'm willing to accept it, but interesting to highlight nonetheless for the sake of discussion.

Comment: @Dan: Just to add, essentially the error happens whenever the rotated coordinates all lie on the same x-axis. E.g. P1 = [0, 0], P2 = [1, 1], and P3 [2, 2] will also do it.

Comment: @Yazid: Ah yes, ATAN2 is essentially a sign-corrected version of ATAN which takes into account which quadrant the points are in. Quite a nifty function, but its availability differs depending on your toolset. Right, j = 0 happens when the center-points are along a single axis, which makes it impossible to connect them to form a triangle. Without a triangle, there can be no triangulation.

Comment: @Yazid: In this case, your best bet is probably to discard the middle point and find the two points of intersection of the two remaining circles, then average those to get the center of the intersection. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect  If there is only one point of intersection, no need to average just use that point. If there are no points of intersection, your data is not triangulation data (which assumes that all three circles / spheres share at least one point in common) and this is another problem entirely.

Comment: @merveotesi Hope it helps, feel free to post a comment or start a discussion if you have any questions.

Comment: @Dan  i need to specify an area. Not a point, but an interval. But the functions seem that they provide points. Do you think that it is a right way to make a for loop and consider all the produced value for 0<r<r1 and for other variables.

Comment: What is "an area", "an interval" in the context of your problem? Perhaps you should ask your own question and leave a link here.

Comment: @Dan i read the post again and found out that the x,y point is the "center" point. I had not known that we get the center. it is ok for now. Thanks

Comment: wow...i didn't know that this thread had so much view since i last viewd couple years ago. 
@Dan. Thanks for the help. I was able to successfully localize within the premises of multiple nodes. However, I was using WiFi APs as nodes and since the 2.4/5Ghz band wasn't too good at penetrating walls so I stoped there. The program works good with little to no wifi obstruction.

Comment: @user1801381 Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm I use in a 3D printer firmware. It avoids rotating the coordinate system, but it may not be the best.

There are 2 solutions to the trilateration problem. To get the second one, replace "- sqrtf" by "+ sqrtf" in the quadratic equation solution.

Obviously you can use doubles instead of floats if you have enough processor power and memory.

```
// Primary parameters
float anchorA[3], anchorB[3], anchorC[3];               // XYZ coordinates of the anchors

// Derived parameters
float Da2, Db2, Dc2;
float Xab, Xbc, Xca;
float Yab, Ybc, Yca;
float Zab, Zbc, Zca;
float P, Q, R, P2, U, A;

...

inline float fsquare(float f) { return f * f; }

...

// Precompute the derived parameters - they don't change unless the anchor positions change.
Da2 = fsquare(anchorA[0]) + fsquare(anchorA[1]) + fsquare(anchorA[2]);
Db2 = fsquare(anchorB[0]) + fsquare(anchorB[1]) + fsquare(anchorB[2]);
Dc2 = fsquare(anchorC[0]) + fsquare(anchorC[1]) + fsquare(anchorC[2]);
Xab = anchorA[0] - anchorB[0];
Xbc = anchorB[0] - anchorC[0];
Xca = anchorC[0] - anchorA[0];
Yab = anchorA[1] - anchorB[1];
Ybc = anchorB[1] - anchorC[1];
Yca = anchorC[1] - anchorA[1];
Zab = anchorB[2] - anchorC[2];
Zbc = anchorB[2] - anchorC[2];
Zca = anchorC[2] - anchorA[2];
P = (  anchorB[0] * Yca
     - anchorA[0] * anchorC[1]
     + anchorA[1] * anchorC[0]
     - anchorB[1] * Xca
    ) * 2;
P2 = fsquare(P);
Q = (  anchorB[1] * Zca
     - anchorA[1] * anchorC[2]
     + anchorA[2] * anchorC[1]
     - anchorB[2] * Yca
    ) * 2;  

R = - (  anchorB[0] * Zca
       + anchorA[0] * anchorC[2]
       + anchorA[2] * anchorC[0]
       - anchorB[2] * Xca
      ) * 2;
U = (anchorA[2] * P2) + (anchorA[0] * Q * P) + (anchorA[1] * R * P);
A = (P2 + fsquare(Q) + fsquare(R)) * 2;

...

// Calculate Cartesian coordinates given the distances to the anchors (La, Lb and Lc)
// First calculate PQRST such that x = (Qz + S)/P, y = (Rz + T)/P.
// P, Q and R depend only on the anchor positions, so they are pre-computed
const float S = - Yab * (fsquare(Lc) - Dc2)
                - Yca * (fsquare(Lb) - Db2)
                - Ybc * (fsquare(La) - Da2);
const float T = - Xab * (fsquare(Lc) - Dc2)
                + Xca * (fsquare(Lb) - Db2)
                + Xbc * (fsquare(La) - Da2);

// Calculate quadratic equation coefficients
const float halfB = (S * Q) - (R * T) - U;
const float C = fsquare(S) + fsquare(T) + (anchorA[1] * T - anchorA[0] * S) * P * 2 + (Da2 - fsquare(La)) * P2;

// Solve the quadratic equation for z
float z = (- halfB - sqrtf(fsquare(halfB) - A * C))/A;

// Substitute back for X and Y
float x = (Q * z + S)/P;
float y = (R * z + T)/P;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Wikipedia calculations, presented in an OpenSCAD script, which I think helps to understand the problem in a visual wayand provides an easy way to check that the results are correct. [Example output from the script](https://github.com/kwikius/Trilateration/blob/master/trilateration_example.png)

```
// Trilateration example
// from Wikipedia
// 
// pA, pB and pC are the centres of the spheres
// If necessary the spheres must be translated
// and rotated so that:
// -- all z values are 0
// -- pA is at the origin
pA = [0,0,0];
// -- pB is on the x axis
pB = [10,0,0];
pC = [9,7,0];

// rA , rB and rC are the radii of the spheres
rA = 9;
rB = 5;
rC = 7;


if ( pA != [0,0,0]){
   echo ("ERROR: pA must be at the origin");
   assert(false);
}

if ( (pB[2] !=0 ) || pC[2] !=0){
   echo("ERROR: all sphere centers must be in z = 0 plane");
   assert(false);
}

if (pB[1] != 0){
   echo("pB centre must be on the x axis");
   assert(false);
}

// show the spheres
module spheres(){
   translate (pA){
      sphere(r= rA, $fn = rA * 10);
   }

   translate(pB){
      sphere(r = rB, $fn = rB * 10);
   }

   translate(pC){
      sphere (r = rC, $fn = rC * 10);
   }
}

function unit_vector( v) = v / norm(v);

ex = unit_vector(pB - pA) ;
echo(ex = ex);

i = ex * ( pC - pA);
echo (i = i);

ey = unit_vector(pC - pA - i * ex);
echo (ey = ey);

d = norm(pB - pA);
echo (d = d);

j =  ey * ( pC - pA);
echo (j = j);

x = (pow(rA,2) - pow(rB,2) + pow(d,2)) / (2 * d);
echo( x = x);

// size of the cube to subtract to show 
// the intersection of the spheres
cube_size = [10,10,10];

if ( ((d - rA) >= rB) || ( rB >= ( d + rA)) ){
   echo ("Error Y not solvable");
}else{
   y = (( pow(rA,2) - pow(rC,2) + pow(i,2) + pow(j,2)) / (2 * j))
      - ( i / j) * x;
   echo(y = y);
   zpow2 = pow(rA,2) - pow(x,2) - pow(y,2);
   if ( zpow2 < 0){
      echo ("z not solvable");
   }else{
      z = sqrt(zpow2);
      echo (z = z);
      // subtract a cube with one of its corners 
      // at the point where the sphers intersect
      difference(){
         spheres();
         translate ([x,y - cube_size[1],z]){
           cube(cube_size);
         }
      }
      translate ([x,y - cube_size[1],z]){
           %cube(cube_size);
      }
  }
}
```