# Multi-points Trilateration to be used with beacon data on Android

Tags: java, android, beacon, indoor-positioning-system, trilateration

I've been struggling for a while with this, I'm currently using *Estimote* Beacon on Android and I'm collecting their **RSSI** and **TxPower** to calculate their **range**. Once I got this data and I know their position (latitude, longitude, altitude), I need to calculate my rough position for an *Indoor Location* purpose.

All the solution provided only are either for three single points or doesn't work. There must be an existing **Java** Solution somewhere since it's a common problem.

---

**Now I know that this was asked before but no answer really helped me in my case. Here is a resume of some of them:**

#### - Solution using three points only:

[Trilateration Method Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761658/trilateration-method-android-java)

[Multi-point trilateration algorithm in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336278/multi-point-trilateration-algorithm-in-java)

[Trilateration Method Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761658/trilateration-method-android-java)

#### - Solution I've tried but gets me a wrong result

[Trilateration Java Algorithm](https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration)

**Another side question If I might ask, What unit of measure should I use for the distance when I'm calculating this? I though it would be the same result whatever distance unit I was using but It turned out the result vary a lot depending if I plug meter or kilometer...**

Comment: When using the trilateration java algorithm, did you convert your position in (lat, long, alt) into Cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) as required by the library? https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration/issues/1

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF for more information.

Comment: The unit of distance and coordinates must be same. I use meters because it is the measurement distance returned by iBeacon devices.